# Shopify (liquid) - add class to div if page template is equal to

Tags: php, html, css, shopify, liquid

Is this possible? I'm working on an existing website and I need to overwrite some styles but only on pages that use my new templates as overwriting the main styles might break the other pages. This is the markup:

```
<div id="page">

  <main role="main" id="MainContent">
     {{ content_for_layout }}
   </main>

   {% section 'footer' %}

</div>
```

So adding a class to the page or `main` element would be ideal.

I've managed to achieve this with an `if` statement to display content but only on a certain template, like this:

```
{% if template == 'page.job-detail' %}
    <!-- CODE HERE -->
{% endif %}
```

Not sure how that'd work in relation to classes on a div? There's probably a few pages I'd need to include so an array or a way I was specify multiple templates would be ideal. Templates like "page.faq", "page.jobs", "page.job-detail".

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just add a custom class to all of your pages and target that based on the templates you like to target.

So you can add the following to the body tag.

```
<body class="template-{{ template | replace: '.', '-' | replace: '/', '-' }}">
```

And you will get classes like:

- template-page-faq
- template-page-jobs
- template-collection
- template-index
- template-customer-login
  etc..

From there you can use only CSS to style only what you need using the above classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your template name, you can add a string that would give you a hint that it is a custom page like so,

```
"page.custom-faq", "page.custom-jobs", "page.custom-job-detail"
```

And you can do this to your HTML

```
<div id="page">

  <main role="main" id="MainContent" class="{% if template.suffix contains 'custom' %}your-custom-class-here{% endif %}">
     {{ content_for_layout }}
   </main>

   {% section 'footer' %}

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
template-{{ template | replace: '.', '-' | handle }}
```

Will print **template-page-donate** for page template with the name "**donate**"